# How do I emulate the permission restrictions of installed programs in VS 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Apologies if this is asked elsewhere, but I could find anything.

I am building an installer for a legacy application that will be installed to users computers. It reads and writes to file, and works fine as long as it isn't in the ProgramFiles folder. I know that if I want to write to files then I need to use the `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` folder.

Unfortunately, I keep being bitten by pieces of code that are using local writes for silly things. Finding them by installing, testing, fixing one by one is tedious.

Is there a way to simulate the requirement for writes to be done in a separate directory when developing/debugging in VS 2019? 
Is there a way to set the `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` folder to be a somewhere else when I'm developing?

Comment: `I keep being bitten by pieces of code that are using local writes for silly things` - Doesn't that mean that the code is NOT using `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`, so changing that would have no effect on the faulty code?

Comment: Anyway you can [use P/Invoke to call `SHSetKnownFolderPath()`](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.SHSetKnownFolderPath) to change that path globally.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes - they aren't using it currently. But if I could make it so the application couldn't write to the bin\debug folder, then anywhere that it couldn't would break in the debugger and I could just see the line where it was happening, instead of having to search. (And yes, I've done searches in code for words like save, but there's some serious silliness going on).

Comment: Simulate the requirement is a huge concept, so I think you should give the Ideas to us so that we can know how to simulate from which side.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT I'm not sure I follow you. I understand that it could be huge, but it probably shouldn't. An idea for simulation would be that any method that tried to write locally - e.g. a call to `new StreamWriter("log.txt")` would throw an exception in debug mode, saying it didn't have permissions. Then, I would know that I wasn't writing locally, since no exceptions were thrown. Given that putting applications into ProgramFiles is a major part of building real software, I would have thought somebody had already solved this.